solana-test-validator fails with 'Archive error: extra entry found'
I'm getting an error while running solana-test-validator
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: io error: Error checking to unpack genesis archive: Archive error: extra entry found: "._genesis.bin" Regular

Logs:
[2024-04-24T06:45:35.752003000Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening blockstore done; blockstore open took 67ms
[2024-04-24T06:45:35.757997000Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] metrics disabled: environment variable not found
[2024-04-24T06:45:35.758071000Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: shred_insert_is_full total_time_ms=0i slot=0i last_index=3i num_repaired=0i num_recovered=0i
[2024-04-24T06:45:35.823304000Z INFO  solana_accounts_db::hardened_unpack] Extracting "test-ledger/genesis.tar.bz2"...


Try this :-
Remove the test-ledger directory and try again to run the solana-test-validator.
rm -rf test-ledger
solana-test-validator

